# The difference between present simple and future simple usage in expressing a future event?

Tags: tense, present-simple

What is the difference between when I said:

> They come, when they are ready.

and

> They **will** come, when they are ready.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They come when they are ready. (No comma)

This does not actually express the future: the present simple expresses things general truths about the present. For example, if I say "I eat cereal for breakfast", it is not limited to just today or the future. It means I eat cereal everyday. I may not have eaten much cereal, and in the future I may instead eat toast, but for the present it is true. Thus, your example means that whenever they are ready, whether it's today, tomorrow, or yesterday, they come.

> They will come when they are ready.

This indicates the future. It is not necessarily as general as the present simple. This just indicates a single instance. When I say, "I will eat cereal when it's time for breakfast", I mean that the next time it is time for breakfast, I'm going to eat cereal - just that once.

Comment: *They come when they are ready* cannot refer to the past.