# Grammar present simple, simple future, present continuous

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Following on from fireeeeeee's answer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/the-difference-between-present-simple-and-future-simple-usage-in-expressing-a-fu), the example "I eat cereal for breakfast" and the descriptions concerned, please let me know what is the difference between that and the sentence "I am eating cereal for breakfast" being used as a temporary action for present.

Answer (score 3):

The present simple is used for quite a few different things, but it's not usually used for things happening right now: see this [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-simple) page for more information. For your example

> I eat cereal for breakfast

This usage of present simple would be taken as a habitual action... you **usually** eat cereal for breakfast.

The present continuous is used for things that are happening right now, so if somebody said - maybe on the phone:

> I am eating cereal for breakfast

I would assume that the person had put down his or her spoon to answer the phone.

Comment: Could you please explain Fireeeeeeeee's comment to me?

Comment: @Babak What are you talking about? Where is this comment?

Comment: I mean this comment from fireeeeeeeee:                                                                                        https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/the-difference-between-present-simple-and-future-simple-usage-in-expressing-a-fu

Comment: @Babak I don't see any comment to you in the question that you referred to: I only see fireeeeeee's answer to hbak's question. Do you understand the difference between answers and comments? What is not clear about fireeeeee's answer?

Comment: @userr2684291 I am asking you to explain to me fireeeeeeeee's answer to hbak's question. I mean both answers. Thank you in advance. And also Following on from fireeeeeee's answer to this question, the example "I eat cereal for breakfast" and the descriptions concerned, please let me know what is the difference between that and the sentence "I am eating cereal for breakfast" being used as a temporary action for present.

Comment: @Babak Take a look at [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/222131/3395).

Comment: @userr2684291I have read this answer. I mean both answers. And also Following on from fireeeeeee's answer to this question, the example "I eat cereal for breakfast" and the descriptions concerned, please let me know what is the difference between that and the sentence "I am eating cereal for breakfast" being used as a temporary action for present.

Comment: @Babak, I don't really agree with the way that fireeeeee answered that question- it's heading in the right direction, but it's a bit mixed up. For this reason, I am not willing to try to explain his or her answer. I have explained as clearly as I can the difference between the two statements in your question.